# How do I pass variables between pages - the OOP way in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, variables

I am trying to convert my website from Wordpress/php to Ruby on Rails and am having trouble grasping the conceptual side of OOP/MVC in Ruby/Rails as it relates to passing variables between views. I have found many answers to how to do it, but I am still unclear exactly what is going on and I think it is because I have not grasped the concept of classes and methods in this particular context.

In PHP I can simply pass a variable to another page like this:

http://myurl.com/scores/?myteam=team1

To do this in Rails - pass one variable (`myteam` in the example previous) between views using a link - then:

1. what methods, classes and objects are involved (and I need to set up) and
2. at what point are they initialized?

Comment: your question is probably to broad. regarding urls, you should read up on restful routing, which rails encourages you to do: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: In Rails when you want to access to the query string params from the view (or from the controller) you have to use [`params`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Read this Controller's Rails guide, especially parameters section: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Basically you will get access to this variable in controller using `params` hash, for this example it will be `params[:myteam]`.